# Undefined reference to function in c++ (g++) with diamond inheritance

Tags: c++, g++

I have simplify my original problem to highlight the issue, so some fixtures may look redundant but they are useful for the rest of my project.

The code of this sample is in a single file `t.cc` and is compiled with `g++ t.cc` with the error:

```
In function `DataOp<int>::value()':
t.cc:(.text._ZN6DataOpIiE5valueEv[_ZN6DataOpIiE5valueEv]+0x28): undefined reference to `Data<int>::data() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code is this:

```cpp
template<typename T> struct Data {
    virtual int data() const = 0;
};

template<typename T> struct DataImpl: virtual Data<T> {
    virtual int data() const override { return 0; }
};

template<typename T> struct DataOp: virtual Data<T> {
    virtual T value() { return Data<T>::data(); }
};

struct OpImpl
    : DataOp<int>
    , DataImpl<int>
{};


int main() {
    OpImpl c;
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly enough, removing `virtual` in `DataOp` implementation removes the linker problem (but I cannot do it easily in the project).

**Updates**

- [Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30036e3e26f6eb7a) to reproduce the results.
- The problem occurs when optimization is disabled, e.g. when -O0 (or no optimization flag) provided to g++.
- Seems to be reproducable on clang++ as well
- Removing templates as [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85f14969511f8f34) removes the error.

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28566b952cbe9417). Provide a [mcve] as required please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ strange, I do manage to reproduce it

Comment: You simply need to provide an implementation, somewhere for data(). 'removing virtual in DataOp' simply hides the problem. As soon as you put a call to .data() and .value() in main() you get the error back. Just implement the .data() function.

Comment: @AndreasDM Show us a link at godbolt or coliru.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ run your example again without optimization -O0

Comment: here is the link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e92710344444ae6 to reproduce.

Comment: @AndreasDM Ah, yes. That reproduces the problem. Not mentioned in the question yet though.

Comment: @Jeffrey `data()` function is implemented in `DataImpl`. Also, removing templates solves the problem with expected result (prints whatever `data()` returns in `DataImpl`)

Comment: @Andre Please put any relevant information into your original question. Just [edit] it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution and posting it here for future references. Adding `this` in `DataOp` solves the problem:

```cpp
template<typename T> struct DataOp: virtual Data<T> {
    virtual T value() { return this->data(); }
};
```